# Bcrypt installation fails in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, bcrypt

I've created a Node-application with MongoDB that runs in Docker. It worked fine until I included [node.bcrypt.js](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js). This makes Node crash with `node-gyp` and `bcrypt`.

The app runs fine locally and on Heroku.

I tried to install a few suggested packages that I found online, that were known to be needed based on error messages. This is why I've added a few extra dependencies, see the `node-gyp`-related line in the dockerfile below.

Now it's gotten where I cannot find any more suggestions, but it still doens't work. I feel it's weird that it works both locally and on Heorku, but not on Docker, and therefore that it's something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
> crowdshelf-server@1.0.0 start /server
> node index.js

  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory `/server/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './lib/topologies/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-58-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! crowdshelf-server@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

This is after I added a few installations to my Dockerfile, see the line after `node-gyp`. Dockerfile:

```
# Base Docker-image on Ubuntu
FROM    ubuntu:latest

#install mongodb
#install git, curl, python and mongo
# node-gyp 
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential make automake gcc g++ cpp libkrb5-dev libc6-dev man-db autoconf pkg-config 

# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

# mongodb setup
# Install NodeJS
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g node-gyp

# Git-clone project
# expose ports
# Install dependencies and start server and database
CMD cd /server && sh start.sh
```

The `starth.sh`-script simply installs dependencies and starts both MongoDB and server.

**EDIT:**
The [repo](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js) tells me to check out the [node-gyp dependencies](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp), but I feel that's been covered by the Dockerfile shown above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is crashing because you are missing some essentials tool for the compilation purposes of Bcrypt. Bcrypt needs to be compiled each time you do `npm install` to crate a version for the operating system that is running on since it is written in C.

For those that would like to use the original Bcrypt, you can run the following docker command:

```
docker run -t -i --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app node:slim sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y python && npm install'
```

Before we do `npm install` we need to:

- **apt-get update**: make sure the package management system knows were to find what we want.
- **apt-get install -y build-essential**: will install all the tools needed to compile C code and more
- **apt-get install -y python**: we add python since it is needed and it is not included in the `build-essential` package.

Once we have all this stuff, we can run `npm install` successfully :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should be the chosen answer so developers are using a bcrypt package that is well tested and most actively being developed

Comment: what to add to the dockerfile?

Comment: I don't understand anything of this answer and why it is upvoted. Can't we just add some line to the DockerFile to be able to work with bcrypt in a container?

Comment: Only because you are new to Docker doesn't mean the answer make no sense. And it is upvoted because it makes sense to people that know Docker. And sure, you can add all the commands that I listed in a clear list under the working example, in to a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply changing the `bcrypt`-library. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) was created based on a similar problem, and provides the same API. The only difference from the library mentioned in my question is:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, function(err, hash) {
    if(!err) callback(hash);
});
```

While in the one linked in this answer:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err, hash) { // Addd nulls
    if(!err) callback(hash);
});
```

Comment: This package has been more recently updated, and is based on the linked package provided in this answer - https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js.  Keeping in mind that bcrypt is updated the most consistently compared to either of these options so if @davidgatti's answer works for you use it over these packages.