# bcrypt fails to install inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, bcrypt

Why exactly I fail to install the bcrypt inside my docker (Dockerfile)?
I attach both the dockerfile and the build error I get

is it related to some versioning issues?

error

```
 make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    make: *** No rule to make target '../.node-gyp/6.10.2/include/node/common.gypi', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
    make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:285:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-46-generic
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
    gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bcrypt installation fails in Docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743605/bcrypt-installation-fails-in-docker)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/41847996/1166285