# Docker deployment fails with bcrypt and python error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Environment: M1 (Apple Silicon)/macOS Monterey 12.3/Docker 4.8.1

I have a node.js project that has MongoDB, mongoose, aws, Twilio as some major dependencies. The project is currently being deployed using a Dockerfile and a container run on an EC2 instance.

Previously, before a change which I cannot pinpoint, the deployed worked perfectly.

Recently, after some changes to some APIs which did not include installing additional packages, the deployment started failing with annoyingly verbose messages which seem to point to `bcrypt` (some kind of dependency issue?) and `python`(not installed?) as the culprits.

I am at a bit of a loss because I haven't changed the configuration, and after a few days of debugging by reinstalling dependencies and specifically targeting both dependencies above, the deployment still doesn't work.

The crash occurs at the final step, `RUN npm ci --only=production`.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- Before someone links to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743605/bcrypt-installation-fails-in-docker/41847996#41847996) related SO thread, I have already tried it but doesn't seem to work for me.
- modifying the Dockerfile with following commands

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y rsync build-essential nodejs
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
```

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16 AS base

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install project dependencies
# a wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

FROM base AS main
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]



FROM main AS test
CMD [ "yarn", "test" ]


FROM main AS builder
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y rsync
ENV NODE_ENV production
# compile JS according to tsconfig.json to dist/
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS deploy
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist/
RUN mkdir -p uploads/
RUN npm ci --only=production
CMD ["node", "dist/server.js"]
```

**ERROR MESSAGES**

```
=> ERROR [deploy 7/7] RUN npm ci --only=production          26.5s
------                                                             
 > [deploy 7/7] RUN npm ci --only=production:                      
#19 5.326 npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.6: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142       
#19 5.490 npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
#19 5.511 npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
#19 7.381 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
#19 9.930 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#19 19.32 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
#19 19.98 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
#19 26.40 npm notice 
#19 26.40 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 8.10.0
#19 26.40 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.10.0>
#19 26.40 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.10.0` to update!
#19 26.40 npm notice 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! code 1
#19 26.40 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/bcrypt
#19 26.40 npm ERR! command failed
#19 26.40 npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
#19 26.40 npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.0 | linux | arm64
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@16.15.0 (node-v93 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | linux | arm64
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info ok 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | linux | arm64
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.104-linuxkit
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
#19 26.40 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/bcrypt
```

Comment: Doesn't look like Python is installed at any point. Not sure why node-gyp relies on it but you could probably add it with `RUN apt-get install -y python3`.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks for the suggestion but I also already tried this and the result is still the same as per OP!

Comment: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/917

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, binaries are missing for Linux arm64 (docker on M1 Mac).

There is an issue open on GitHub: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/917